# PDF rendering issue using tcpdf

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, gd, tcpdf

I’ve developed a feature in my application which takes some images and rendered to one pdf according to user. This functionality is working okay in my stage server but this shows me “server error” on production.

I verified error logs of apache and I found following errors

```
libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area

Corrupt JPEG data: 234 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

The application is created on cakephp, the library for rendering pdf is tcpdg and staging and production servers are on ubuntu. I’ve consult some senior guys, they all are saying this is GD problem.

The environment on stage server

```
PHP 5.3.3-0.dotdeb.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct  1 2010 08:49:29)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
```

The environment on production server

```
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 19:12:47)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
```

Please recommend me any risk free solution.

Comment: have you compared the versions of every software involved in both the test and production servers?

Comment: What are the types of your images? because you have both errors for png and jpg ..

Comment: @Naryl which softwares you are talking about ?

Comment: @Nelson user can upload any type of images.

Comment: anything that could trigger an error. I'm asking you if your test server and production server has the same version of: PHP (and any PHP module you use), web server, etc. Anything your application is using to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During diagnosis this issue. I noticed that **[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)**   module wasn't loaded on our staging server. That's why it was working on staging server. We disabled it from production server and it works. It was causing some conflicts with GD.

I commented out following extension

```
extension=imagick.so
```

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

There are some garbage bytes after the end of the image for any reason which stop it to work.

You can do a work around to find "\xFF\xD9" in your image bytes which represents EOI (End of Image) and where ever you find it chop the bytes after it. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Your live machine generating these garbage bytes might be kernel is sending these bytes or some other reason you can try the mentioned solution on live.

Comment: Mention "some other reasons". I can afford such changes on production server.